# navigationBar.IntrinsicContentSize.height doesn't match the actual bar's size

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I tried to set the position of a component by using CGRect containing the position.

```
 pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRect(x:0.0, y:(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.intrinsicContentSize.height)!, width:self.view.frame.width, height:self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)
```

and y is set to `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.intrinsicContentSize.height`

But when I run my app on the simulator, it shows the menu bar underneath the navigation bar. I don't know why. I already set the y coordinate to the height of navigation bar. Please help.

[image]

And this is my StoryBoard.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set this for the view controller that hides under the navigation bar

```
viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```